# Display Data from database based on dropdown selection Using Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

*unable to get contnt from daabase when we select a value from database.Please help me regarding this.*

***drop.php***

I Have a page as drop.php which contains the following code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showUser(id) {
    //get the selected value

    //make the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getuser.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {option : id},
        success: function(data) {
           document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML=data;
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("database.php");
include("session.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM invoicetable WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo'<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">';
echo '<option value="">'.'--- Select ---'.'</option>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';   
}
echo '</select>';?>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b></b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

***getuser.php***

```
<?php
include("database.php");
include("session.php");
$sql="SELECT address FROM invoicetable WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1' style='width:500'>
<tr>
<th>Address</th>

</tr>";

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
?>
```

*unable to get contnt from daabase when we select a value from database.Please help me regarding this.*
    Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two fields with same username.For resolve this issue you have to make **id** column in table is primary key.So that **id** filed will be different for both the users that have same username.

$id = $_REQUEST['option'];

```
$sql="SELECT address FROM invoicetable WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]' AND id=$id";
```

Try this it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in getuser.php

```
$userid = $_request['option'];
$sql="SELECT address FROM invoicetable WHERE Id='$userid'";
```

Comment: i have two fields with same username.username stored in session

Answer (score 0):

A simple mistake in this is in getuser.php file you are not taking the userId from ajax call rather than you are using SESSION_DATA which remain unchanged.

you can just take userId as 
      $id = $_GET['option'];

and change query to

```
  $sql="SELECT address FROM invoicetable WHERE id=$id";
```

Comment: i have two fields with same username.username stored in session